# Looking for a Font That "Speaks" with a Brooklyn Accent

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts

I am in the process of a designing a cover for a book.

I have been searching for a font that "speaks" with a Brooklyn accent, if you know what I mean, for use in the title.

I thought of the old film, "A Tree Grows in Brooklyn":

[image]

But I could not identify the font exactly; besides, for my purposes, a sketchy handwriting font might be more suitable.

Can someone confidently suggest such a *Brooklyn* font?

Incidentally, if someone can identify the font in the above picture and where I might find it, that would be very helpful. So far, using a font identifier, I have come up with lots of approximations---some decent, some not so good.

Thank you.

Comment: The average of modern day Brooklyn has a very different feel than that font I'd say. But it is a very diverse area so no one font can represent all of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts don't really "say" anything. It's the overall **context** of any design that conveys a message. In most designs, almost *any* font *could* work it's merely a matter of using other visual elements to convey the "attitude" or "message."

Just a quick [image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=brooklyn+NY+designs&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi4jbWEuqL8AhX6B0QIHQGWD-sQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=brooklyn+NY+designs&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECAAQQzoGCAAQCBAeOgYIABAHEB5QvwhYoAxg8g1oAHAAeACAAbUBiAGrA5IBAzMuMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=i26vY_ibM_qPkPIPgay-2A4&bih=1256&biw=1936&hl=en) shows all sorts of fonts used for "Brooklyn" - from scripts, to serifs - including slab serifs, to sans serifs.

[image]

What *any* font may or may not "say" is subjective and each individual may have a different connotation associated with *any* font.

If the desire is to find a high contrast serif font, @Tetsujin has a great suggestion in **[Bodoni](https://www.myfonts.com/products/bodoni-book-atf-bodoni-434328)**, but there are *many* others ([1](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/tiffany-font-itc), [2](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/jeanne-moderno-font-steve-mehallo), [3](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/eckhart-font-rohh), [4](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/hera-big-font-lucas-sharp), [5](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/regional-font-sudtipos), [6](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/vibertus-font-cercurius)).

Comment: Many thanks @Scott.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost Bodoni, which you probably already own…
Yours left, Bodoni right, stretched vertically.

[image]

I would have no clue what a Brooklyn accent would look like… unless you spelled 'coffee' as 'cwarfee' ;)